# input type text field giving fixed error 2147483647

Tags: php, mysql

I have input type field as mobile but every time it feeds in this particular value in my database ie **2147483647** irrespective whatever values we fill

```
td><span class="style5">Mobile</span></td>
  <td><input type="number" name="mob" class="text-input" maxlength="10" /></td>
```

connecting code `$Mobile=  mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['mob']);`

```
"INSERT INTO old VALUES('','$ID','$Car','$Name','$Name','$Gender','$DOB','$Age','$Mobile','$A   ddress','$City','$EmailId')"
```

Comment: what's the datatype for that field in your Database?

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated, and has been for a while.  Stop using it.

Comment: Oh, and for reference..."phone numbers" are not numbers -- they're strings that happen to contain digits.  If `mob` is meant to be a phone number, make the column a `char(10)` instead.  (Possibly bigger if you want to support international numbers...but `char(10)` is big enough for US and Canadian phone numbers.)

Comment: Thanks dany such a mediocre mistake

Comment: @cHao but what about codes which are made earleir

Comment: New code written for ext/mysql is by definition a steaming pile of crap.  Code that was written before mysqli/PDO is a semi-special case, and is the *only* reason ext/mysql hasn't been removed from PHP altogether.  Eventually, though, even that won't save it; code that used it will break in some future version of PHP.  Code using ext/mysql should be migrated to mysqli or PDO, else there'll come a point where it won't run on a modern server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column in a signed INT which holds integers up to 2147483647. Your value is clearly larger than that. You will need to use BIGINT or VARCHAR for that data depending on what it represents (phone numbers should be stored as VARCHAR/CHAR since you are not going to be doing math with them).

See [Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)