# 2147483647 input can't submit form

Tags: php, html, forms

yesterday one of my client put 2147483647 as her account number, and received a `forbidden page error`.

When I tried , I also got forbidden page error when submitting the  input '2147483647'.

This is my test form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This form will give forbidden page error. If i put '2147483646', I get no error.. An way to get no error is to get rid  of name attribute.. Please help.. I get this error for each form on my website.

Comment: Please refer to these links they can give you some hints -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639108/input-type-text-field-giving-fixed-error-2147483647 and http://www.codeitive.com/7ymNXVkPWq/input-type-text-field-giving-fixed-error-2147483647.html

Comment: why you store text as interger?

Comment: *"i got no error"* - because you're not checking for errors.

Comment: @Dagon doesn't matter; I gave it *the gold*.

Answer (score 0):

I think your colomn type in the database table is int. Please change it to bigint or varchar

Answer (score 0):

Integers hold up to 2147483647,
You will need to use BIGINT or VARCHAR
if you are not going to be doing math with them there's no point storing them as a integer, instead acount numbers should be stored as VARCHAR/CHAR;

> INT = bytes 4 min -2147483648 max 2147483647